# Facebook location display null

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am integrating facebook login.I need to display friends name and location. name is displaying but location is showing null. The below is my code. Tell me where i am going wrong.

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
   {
        NSLog(@"active fb session");
        FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];

        [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                      NSDictionary* result,
                                                      NSError *error)
        {
            NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
            NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
            for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
                NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.location);
        }
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the permission: **friends_location** in your login code.

Note that:

1. API for getting the friends location: `/me/friends?fields=location,name`; and you're calling for default: `/me/friends`
2. You'll get the location as an object:

   ```
   "location": {
      "id": "130646063637019", 
      "name": "Noida, India"
   },
   ```

   And you'll not get location for all the friends of-course (due to their privacy settings).

[Live Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dlocation)

Comment: @Sahil Mittal can you help me? What is the reason for that: from one user I get field "location" in result from Facebook (my example is location =     {
        id = 107677462599905;
        name = "Minsk, Belarus";
    }; but from other users I don't receive this field, but both of them have current location in Facebook profile.

Comment: De-authorize that user by removing the app from the settings and then try again!